How to disable Realtek logging to a file?
I need help with this Realtek logging too much unwanted data on SSD and contributing to unwanted reads and writes. My HP laptop has an inbuilt Realtek WiFi card and its drivers. However, the drivers were automatically installed via Windows Update. My drivers are up-to-date (as far as Windows 10 is concerned).
As per the screenshot below, Realtek keeps writing nonsense data in a log file, and the file size keeps increasing to 100+ MB. These two screenshots are relative comparisons of how, within a few hours, the file size keeps increasing as Realtek dumps garbage and unnecessary writes on my SSD.


Here is a detailed view of the files inside that folder location. Since it contains my laptop's WiFi drivers, I can't just delete/uninstall them, as doing so will cause non-connectivity to the wireless network.

Here is another screenshot of what's inside the log file.

How do I disable this unwanted logging?

Not sure if this is available, but in Device Manager, right-click the Realtek device, select Properties, and on the Advanced tab, look for a setting to control logging level or debug mode. Also, look in Windows Services for any containing "Realtek" or "Rtk" and temporarily* stop and disable them for a while -- if the WiFi (and Bluetooth) still work, leve the service off.

Thank you @DrMoishePippik for pointing this out. I was able to find the culprit hidden in the services under fancy and scary name as "RtkWiFiManServ". This WiFi manager was labeled as "WiFi Manager" I thought it would hamper my internet connection, but internet is working fine after disabling it and it has stopped unwanted logging. Thank you once again.

I found the hidden service as a culprit. It was named "WiFi Manager" as if it was responsible for internet connectivity. It was confusingly named "Realtek Wireless Manager Service."
I disabled that service, and Realtek stopped drilling my SSD with a nonsense log.

